# TThread Wait for User Input

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, vcl

I have a `TThread` Instance and I would like to wait for a user input.
The Thread loads something, waits for the user to click a button and then continues it's task.

I was thinking about setting a global bool to true, yet this wouldn't work too well with instances I think and the thread would have to check the var state in a loop and it seems a little unprofessional.

Is there a safe method for the tthread class to wait for a user input?

Comment: I would have two system events, one as a flag that the thread should die and one that it should continue the paused process. I would be waiting for their signalled state with `WaitForMultipleObjects` function with the `INFINITE` timeout and if one of them becomes signalled, take an action. It is then easy to signal them from some method called e.g. `AbortExecution` and `ContinueExecution`.

Comment: @TLama Something like the thread suspends itself and a button would resume it?

Comment: The thread would stay blocked on the line with `WaitForMultipleObjects` for an infinite time or until you signal one of those events. On that button click you'd just call the thread's method `ContinueExecution` which would signal its own private system event.

Comment: @TLama Ohhh. I got you. That's a good idea as well. Thank you.

Comment: I've been thinking about [`this approach`](http://pastebin.com/zTuc9WYN). But it's of course tied to Windows platform, which `TEvent` should not be.

Comment: @TLama I added the `windows` tag so this would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a TEvent from the SyncObjs unit.

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
public
    SignalEvent : TEvent;
    procedure Execute; override;
end;


TMyForm = class(TForm)
    procedure Button1Click(Sender : TObject);
public
    myThread : TMyThread;
end;
```

The thread does its work, then waits for the event to be signalled by the button click event. By using a TEvent you can also specify a timeout. (or 0 to wait indefinitely).

```
procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender : TObject);
begin
    // Tell the thread that the button was clicked.
    myThread.SignalEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
    waitResult : TWaitResult;
begin
    // do stuff

    // Wait for the event to signal that the button was clicked.
    waitResult := SignalEvent.WaitFor(aTimeout);

    if waitResult = wrSignaled then
    begin
        // Reset the event so we can use it again
        SignalEvent.ResetEvent;
        // do some more stuff
    end else 
        // Handle timeout or error.
end;
```

Comment: I just kinda suggested that below, but I would probably use a boolean property and signal the event in the setter.  That would allow a 'TStopGoThread' to be inserted into the inheritance chain with further descendants overriding the setter.

Comment: Also, it's a wrapper round a Windows Event class.  Semaphore is a different primitive.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Brief brain fart. Corrected. Your property suggestion is entirely valid but down to the actual implementation. I supplied a very basic code example to demonstrate it's usage. I wouldn't expect it to be copied directly.

Answer (score 2):

I used Delphi long ago, so unfortunately I can't provide very specific solution, but I can point you to right direction. You basically need signalling event (`TEvent` in Delphi's terminology). You can find more info and example here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Waiting_for_a_Task_to_Be_Completed

So essentially event is an object on what you can wait and signal. So the signal waiting for input should wait on event, and on button pressed method you signal event, and thread will unfreeze.

Comment: This would be just a global scope `TEvent` as I thought with a `bool`. I guess that's the only thing I can do then. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't have to be global.  The TEvent can be a private field of the TThread descendant and you could create it in either the ctor overload or at the top of the Execute method.  You could then have a public boolean property for Stop/Go and signal the event in the setter/getter.